# Why doesn't the loop start when comparing float result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal is that when sleep_time reaches 0.1 it starts a loop where it prints number.

```
import time

number = 0
sleep_time = 1

# Main code
while sleep_time >= 0.1:
    if sleep_time == 0.1:
        while True:
            print(number)
    number += 1
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(number)
    sleep_time -= 0.1
```

This prints numbers from 1 to 10 and then it stops.

Comment: because when it reaches 0.1 the loop should start

Comment: For the sake of reusability of the question could you include your expected output?

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue of floating-point imprecision, consider:

```
>>> sleep = 1
>>> dec = 0.1
>>> for _ in range(9):
...     sleep -= dec
...
>>> sleep
0.10000000000000014
>>> sleep == 0.1
False
>>>
```

When dealing with this sort of thing, usually `math.isclose` is a viable solution:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.isclose(sleep, 0.1)
True
>>>
```

The following should be [required reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Other approaches would be to use only `int` objects, or to use `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I agree, generally that is best. Or to use `decimal.Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5079316).

```
x = 1.0
for _ in range(9):
    x -= 0.1

print(x) # 0.10000000000000014
print(x == 0.1) # False
```

When exact arithmetic is required for a problem which handles an atomic quantity, it's better to use `int` than `float`. In this case your atomic quantity being a tenth of a second, we'll let `1` represent 0.1 second.

```
import time

number = 0
sleep_time = 10 # in tenth of seconds

# Main code
while sleep_time >= 1:
    if sleep_time == 1:
        while True:
            print(number)
    number += 1
    time.sleep(sleep_time / 10)
    print(number)
    sleep_time -= 1
```